# How can I set all negative values in a dictionary to be zero?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Working on a lil' c# browser game where I use this dictionary to keep track on several resources in the game:

```
public Dictionary <String, int> resource = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

Amoungst those, "gold", which changes for each tick.

```
protected void timerMinute_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
resource["gold"] += (resProduction["gold"] - resConsumption["gold"])
}
```

Now, if consumption is greater than production, the number decreases. I want to deny the resource from becoming negative. I know that I can do this for each tick:

```
if (resource["gold"] < 0)
{
resource["gold"] = 0;
}
```

However, I have many many more resources to keep track on, so while I could write the aforementioned code for each, I just wondered if someone had a clever way to check all values in the dictionary *resource*, and turn any negatives into zero.

Edit: Thanks for all the great suggestions to the problem here! As a newbie with c#, I'm not quite familiar with it all ^^

Comment: This may sound crazy, but have you considered using an unsigned data type such as uint instead of int? That would guarantee a non-negative value without writing the extra code.

Comment: Bad idea, -1 would become 65535 for instance

Comment: Except of course that decrementing it would just wrap around to the highest value.

Comment: @Thomas And thus was born the maximum money trick in every badly designed video game.

Comment: I think everyone is overthinking it.  You don't need to make any major changes to your current design.. you certainly could... however.. with just one line change you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make your own dictionary class that ensures the values are non-negative. This is a simple example, but you could make it generic and extensible pretty easily.

```
public class ValidatedDictionary : IDictionary<string, int>
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    protected virtual int Validate(int value)
    {
        return Math.Max(0, value);
    }
    public void Add(string key, int value)
    {
        _dict.Add(key, Validate(value));
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _dict.ContainsKey(key);
    }
    // and so on: anywhere that you take in a value, pass it through Validate
```

Comment: A `Dictionary<string, uint>` (note: unsigned integer values) also ensures non-negative values. But see my answer for problems with that.

Comment: I don't get how SO forum work. I answer first and say to have a special class that does it, someone else later writes the code for it and gets 7 votes. And some other days I see people asking questions and everyone goes like "do your homework yourself we won't help". Where is the cursor ?

Comment: @Thomas Code examples are part of most good answers. If the question is apparently a homework question, it's good to provide direction, and some code examples, but not so much code that they can copy/paste the solution. That's my opinion anyway: the nature of SO means that there aren't any hard rules for what gets voted up and what doesn't, so you can't put scores under a microscope. Some of it is probably simply that I got votes earlier, so people just looked at my question, upvoted it, and went away without seeing yours.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `TValue` like `uint` that does not allow negative values at all, as in:

```
Dictionary<string, uint>
```

But note that your subtraction will "wrap around" if you subtract something big from something small, with `uint`. So you should be carefull when you subtract! So maybe it is not easier to use `uint` after all, but it will guarantee you that your values are non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways :

```
for (String s in resourceNames)
  resource[s] = max(0, resProduction[s] - resConsumption[s]);
```

or have implement a special dictionary class that does this

Comment: The question is about C#, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the operation and expose only that which is required. The point is *only the contract is exposed*. (I also generally prefer to work with localized contracts, which is why I don't suggest implementing `IDictionary` directly: it makes a very poor Service.)

#### Use encapsulation to hide the Dictionary:

```
class Ticker {
   Dictionary<string, int> dict = ..;

   // I don't actually know what contract you need
   public Decay(string symbol, int value) {
      // Handle all logic uniformly here such as checking to make sure it can't
      // go negative.
   }
}
```

Then:

```
resourceStash.Decay("gold", fortKnox);
```

#### Or, use encapsulation to hide the Value:

That is, make it a `Dictionary<symbol, ResourceValue>` (where `ResourceValue` is again special and encapsulates the required logic).

Then:

```
resources["gold"].LessenLoad(nuggetCount);
```

(Or you could overload the `-` operator to make `ResourceValue` behave more like an integer).

Answer (score 0):

How about a one line change to your current design?

There are plenty of harder ways to do this but the easiest way I can see is to just modify your current method to the following..

```
protected void timerMinute_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resource["gold"] = Math.Max(0, (resource["gold"] + resProduction["gold"] - resConsumption["gold"]));
}
```

**EDIT:** Loop through each resource type?

```
protected void timerMinute_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var resourceName in resource.Keys)
    {
        resource[resourceName] = Math.Max(0, (resource[resourceName] + resProduction[resourceName] - resConsumption[resourceName]));
    }
}
```

Comment: “I have many many more resources to keep track on, so while I could write the […] code for each, I just wondered if someone had a clever way to check all values in the dictionary resource”

Comment: sorry... I obviously missed the 'clever' bit... however to go with my previous 'easy' themed answer I've edited my answer to just loop through all resources.